# JavaScript SyntaxError in Chromium: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, android-webview

I'm trying to execute a JavaScript function to see if an element exists in a webpage, but instead of receiving true/false, I'm getting a SyntaxError.

JavaScript:

`javascript: var foo = function() { if (document.getElementById('bar') != null) return true; else return false; }; foo();`

Error:

`I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list", source:  (1)`

I've run it through several JavaScript formatters, but I can't find the source of the error. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this an on* attribute?

Comment: Cannot reproduce error. Are there portions of steps to reproduce error missing at Question?

Comment: Can you add an [mcve] using a stacksnippet?

Comment: Apologies, I tagged this as android-webview, but I forgot to include that the error occurs when loading a webpage into an Android WebView, and evaluating JavaScript once the webpage has loaded.

Comment: Does it help to remove the `javascript:` label? How about to simplify the code since it seems you don't really need a function. This should do exactly the same: `document.getElementById("bar") != null`

Comment: If I remove the `javascript:` label, then I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var". I can try removing the function though, and see if that works.

Comment: @squint I still receive "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Comment: My guess is this is a nested quotes issue.

Answer (score 2):

i had a similar issue when triggering a javascript function in a WebView from the Android native code:

```
    wb.loadUrl("javascript:process('" + myParameter + ");");
```

The problem was solved adding a ' before the first closing parenthesis:

```
    wb.loadUrl("javascript:process('" + cff + "');");
```

Hope this help, although i can`t see such an error in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and the issue was having singular quotes ' inside a string I wanted to send through javascript.

```
WebView.loadUrl("javascript:function('" + stringToSend + "')")
```

The stringToSend variable had singular quotes ' inside it, which, to javascript, ended the string. Javascript expected a ) after the end of the string, hence the error.

To fix this I added the escape character \ in front of every singular quote ' by looping through the stringToSend backwards and inserting them.